# this.variable vs variable child scope

Tags: javascript, closures

I have some JS code where I want to return my global object's instance in its child method (think fluent interface):

```
myGlobalVar = function() {
    this.self = this;
    this.Whatever = function() {
        //return self; // why does that FAIL??
        return this.self; // why does that WORK??
    }
}
```

I would have assumed that I'd `return self` but that fails. `return this.self` succeeds but I figured `this` in the child function would refer to said function. Why does this work?

Comment: there is no free-floating variable "self" to return... the meaning of this does not change in the child function as shown.

Comment: Why is that so, @dandavis ?

Comment: you have no var keyword or arguments, so there are no named variables.

Comment: in other words, you can just "return this" since this==self...

Comment: @dandavis Why does the meaning of `this` not change in the child function?

Comment: The instance can be hit inside the constructor and inside own methods as this, so it's really just a mis-understanding more than an actual problem. if you detach from the instance or apply/call when using the method, you can change the meaning of this. but if you call myGlobalVar.Whatever(), this==myGlobalVar inside. also, self is used already, so use something else like "that" to avoid potential conflicts down the line.

Comment: is it running in a strict mode

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f9JXN/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny: that's just the pre-defined global self making an appearance...

Comment: @dandavis yes... that is why I'm confused... unless op is not using it as a constructor both should work

Comment: You will need to differentiate between *property* and *variable*. See [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript the value of `this` in a function is determined by the caller of the function.

When you call `obj.method()`, the value of `this` is set to `obj` inside of `method()`.  So, in your example above, when you call `myGlobalVar.Whatever()`, the value of `this` inside of `Whatever()` will be `myGlobalVar` so to reference `sefl`, you use `this.self` as you have discovered.

`self` all by itself does not work because it is not a variable in the current scope all by itself.  It's a property of `myGlobalVar` and thus can ONLY be referenced as either `myGlobalVar.self` or `this.self` when `this === myGlobalVar`.  Javascript does not automatically check properties on the current object in order to resolve a symbol.  You can only reach a property of an object by specifically referencing the object that hosts the property as in `this.self`.

---

There are other ways that the value of `this` can be altered.  If `Whatever()` is called without the `obj` context such as:

```
var fn = myGlobalVar.Whatever;
fn();
```

Then, the value of this will be either the global object in regular JS or `undefined` in JS strict mode.

---

There are also `.call()` and `.apply()` methods on every function that allow you to directly specify what you want the `this` value to be set to inside the method as in `myGlobalVar.Whatever.call(myOtherGlobalVar)`.

Comment: Now *this* answer makes sense to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you try and access a variable, JavaScript, first look for that variable in the current function scope, next, in the enclosed functions scope and then finally in the global scope. In your case, `self` is a member of `this`, global object. When you say `this.self`, and if `this` refers to the global scope, `this.self` is same as the `self`. Unless you change the current context, `this` will refer to the global object and it should work. Check the following example to understand better.

```
myGlobalVar = function() {
    this.self = "thefourtheye";
    this.Whatever = function() {
        console.log(self);
        console.log(this.self);
        console.log(this.self === self);
    }
}

var b = {
    self: "thethirdeye"
}

myGlobalVar();
Whatever();
console.log("-------------------");
Whatever.apply(b);
```

**Output**

```
thefourtheye
thefourtheye
true
-------------------
thefourtheye
thethirdeye
false
```

When I am calling `Whatever`, the second time, I am setting the current context to object `b`, with apply. So, now `this` points to `b`. Now, `self` is different from `this.self`. When I refer `self`, it looks up the hierarchy and finds `self` in the global scope, it prints `thefourtheye`, when I say `this.self`, it looks up `self` in `b` and it prints `thethirdeye`. Hope its clear now.

Comment: how does this.self return correctly for OP if 'this' will not be available in Whatever()?

Comment: @dandavis We are not returning `this.self`, we are returning `self` :)

Comment: i meant that you said "The problem here is this. You are making a reference to this, in this itself. So, it will not be available within Whatever", when clearly the OP can indeed see this and it's property "self".

Comment: @thefourtheye try my code, it works. Why does it work if `this.self = this`?

Comment: Can't give the answer out twice, but you get an upvote for sure. Thanks for the explanation!